# PHP split mysql data into multiple lines

Tags: php

I currently have a problem with splitting data that is retrieved from database.

Example: when I display it, it shows `data1 data2 data3 data4`. But I want it to be displayed like

- Data1 Data2
- Data3 Data4

I have tried several ways to do it, but I failed to do so. Is there anything I have to change in my code in order to achieve that?

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table">

    function pingAddress($ip,$kiosk) {
                    $fp = @fSockOpen($ip,80,$errno,$errstr,1);
                    $checkCount = 0;                
                    if(is_resource($fp)){
                        if($fp) { 
                            $status=0; 
                            fclose($fp); 
                            echo '<td><p><b>'.$kiosk.'</b></p><img src="images/green.png" width=50px height=50px></img></td>';  
                            $checkCount++;

                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo '<td><p><b>'.$kiosk.'</b></p><img src="images/red.png" width=50px height=50px></img></td>';        
                        $checkCount++;

                    }
                    if($checkCount % 2 ==0){
                        echo '</table><table class="table">';
                    }

                }
                // Some IP Address
                pingAddress("192.168.1.0","Kuantan (35)"); 
                pingAddress("192.168.1.1","UTC Kuantan (36)"); 
                pingAddress("192.168.1.2","Temerloh (37)"); 
                pingAddress("192.168.1.3","Bentong (6)"); 

</table>
```

The result should be shown like this:

```
 - Kuantan 35 UTC Kuantan 36
 - Temerloh 37 Bentong 6
```

Comment: Just use `<tr></tr>` .

Comment: Display it in the <table></table> it will work for you.

Comment: At the first place, you might use [ArrayChunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) to slice your data into your size.

Comment: @Iffi May i know what do you mean by <table></table>? As i already have a table in there already why still need extra?

Comment: @MarcusTan you have already tables so just add <tr> tags .. Start new <tr> and at the end of function put condition if($checkCount == 2){ echo '</tr>' } Its mean close tr tag if output is display two time and than start tr new tag.

Comment: @Iffi I had try to use that but it also won't work. Is anything wrong with my code? Because i call the function independently and show the result, i'm nt using any loop

Comment: You need to do some enhancement in code to convert to loop code than you can get the results that you want.

Comment: I had try to use loop ,but when i change to loop my function won't work...i not sure why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You has ignored a `<tr>` in your code, this split the data in rows to archieve your goal.

Comment: Hi there, i had try to put <tr> in my code but still the same result...it display in a line for the result where i wanted to split them into a new line after 2 data

Answer (score 1):

I think there is problem with your code, because as I see you first close and after open table tag - it means in first time you call the function you'll close missing tag.
After that if you like to show two results on the row, it means you have to add global variable ( or add another one external variable in call ) which rule where the current result will be shown - on first or second column.
And on the end - I think it is bad practice to enclose single result on table tags - at least I can't see the meaning for it. Why don't you use  for example?